# X axis mirror in sculpt mode not being symmetrical

Tags: mirror, sculpt-mode

I'm in sculpt mode and when I turn on the mirror for the x axis it is not symmetrical as you can see in the image below. Is there a way to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sculpt symmetry is based on your object transforms. Try to apply all transforms (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> > *All transforms*  or *Object > Apply > All Transforms*).

When the symmetry dot seems to be snapping to random spots on the object, it's likely that the rotation transform is not applied to it.

You can check these values in the side panel on the 3D view while in *Object Mode* (Shortcut  <kbd>N</kbd>, then *Item > Transform*)